# Calling tasks from different testbenches systemverilog

Tags: task, system-verilog

I am trying to call tasks defined in an interface file from a testbench file. the task is defined as

```
task master_monitor(
                   output bit [ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] addr,
                   output bit [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] data,
                   output bit we                    
                  );

          while (!cyc_o) @(posedge clk_i);                                                  
          while (!ack_i) @(posedge clk_i);
          addr = adr_o;
          we = we_o;
          if (we_o) begin
            data = dat_o;
          end else begin
            data = dat_i;
          end
          while (cyc_o) @(posedge clk_i);                                                  
     endtask
```

In my testbench, the interface is instantiated as wb_bus and I am trying to call the task in the following way:

```
wire [WB_DATA_WIDTH-1:0] dat_wr_o;
wire [WB_DATA_WIDTH-1:0] adr;
wire we;
initial
begin
    repeat(10) begin
    wb_bus.master_monitor(adr, dat_wr_o, we);

    end
end
```

when I simulate this on modelsim, I end up with these errors:

```
   ** Error: (vsim-3047) ../testbench/top.sv(52): actual value for formal 'data' of 'master_read' must be assignable.
#    Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /top File: ../testbench/top.sv
# ** Error: (vsim-3047) ../testbench/top.sv(53): actual value for formal 'we' of 'master_monitor' must be assignable.
#    Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /top File: ../testbench/top.sv
# ** Error: (vsim-3047) ../testbench/top.sv(53): actual value for formal 'data' of 'master_monitor' must be assignable.
#    Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /top File: ../testbench/top.sv
# ** Error: (vsim-3047) ../testbench/top.sv(53): actual value for formal 'addr' of 'master_monitor' must be assignable.
#    Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /top File: ../testbench/top.sv
```

Am i passing the variables in the right way? Can someone help me out?

Comment: The middle fragment of your example is definitely wrong. You either call the task in a wrong way or incorrectly declared the signals. It is impossible to say in which wrong direction you moved  without seeing more of the code.

Comment: I have updated the task definition

Comment: Where am I going wrong in calling the task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass wire signals like `adr` to the output arugment of a task. Either change them to `logic`, or create intermediate variables that you pass to the task arguments, and then `assign` them to the wires.